# Wordpress plugin, send string to JS function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

so I created a plugin for a wordpress site. In it I want to call a JavaScript function (with a string) that is inside a file that I just enqueued. But nothing is happening. Can someone see the error?

```
function tsd_getscript() {
    if(is_single()){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'imagefix-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagefix.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
        echo "<script>alertText('TEST');</script>";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tsd_getscript' );
```

And in imagefix.js this is the code:

```
function alertText(string){
    alert(string);
}
```

All I get is the console saying alertText is undefined. So it's like it doesn't load the js file at all.. am I missing something obvious here?

Edit: So due to the undefined I checked the source and the alert code is loaded in the head but the script in the body, how do I make the alert be done after the script is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Well `wp_enqueue_script()` doesn't immediately output the script to the browser, it queues it and will be rendered when called for in the template.

However, when you `echo` your `<script>` tag, that does immidiately output it and so at that point, your external script hasn't even been sent to the browser, let alone loaded.

To demonstrate, you can wrap the call in `window.onload`

```
echo "<script>window.onload = function(){ alertText('TEST'); };</script>";
```

But a proper solution, for example is to make your script output somewhere in the template like the footer:

```
function do_inline_script(){
    echo "<script>alertText('TEST');</script>";
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'do_inline_script' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I understand the problem now. But I have a problem with this approach. I don't want this action to be done unless the conditions above are met. I only want it do be executed if page is_single(). Do you know how to achieve this? Can I simply put the add_action in there?